# Parsing a SOAP response

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

I have been spending hours trying to parse a SOAP response that I have no control over. I have tried numerous methods I found on SO with no luck.

Here is the response body I get from edge browser:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:gXMLQueryResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:com-photomask-feconnect-IFeConnect" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<return xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version = &apos;1.0&apos; encoding = &apos;UTF-8&apos;?&gt;
&lt;ROWSET&gt;
   &lt;ROW num=&quot;1&quot;&gt;
      &lt;CUSTOMER_NAME&gt;HITACHI&lt;/CUSTOMER_NAME&gt;
   &lt;/ROW&gt;
&lt;/ROWSET&gt;
</return>
</ns1:gXMLQueryResponse>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get the CUSTOMER_NAME value.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$client = new SoapClient($urla, array('trace' => 1));

try {
    $result = $client->__soapCall("gXMLQuery", $params);

    $response = ($client->__getLastResponse());

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);


    $rows = $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('ns1', true)->gXMLQueryResponse->return->ROWSET->ROW;

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $customer = $row->CUSTOMER_NAME;
        echo $customer;

    }



} catch (SoapFault $e) {


}
```

Comment: When I echo the response, this is what I get:

<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?> 
<ROWSET> 
    <ROW num="1"> <CUSTOMER_NAME>HITATCHI</CUSTOMER_NAME>       </ROW> </ROWSET> "

Answer (score 1):

`return` is a string, you need to parse it first before you can access it using SimpleXML.

First you need to decode the string using `html_entity_decode`, after that you can load the decoded string with `simplexml_load_string`:

```php
$return = $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('ns1', true)->gXMLQueryResponse->return;

$decodedReturn = html_entity_decode($return, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
$rowset = simplexml_load_string($decodedReturn);

echo $rowset->ROW->CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

Comment: fromvega, how would I do that?

Comment: how did you get a value into the $return value, or should that be the SOAP response?

Comment: I get an error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\appa\soap.php on line 84.

it's this code: echo $rowset->ROW->CUSTOMER_NAME;

Comment: Make sure that $decodedReturn holds a valid XML string and then use it as a reference to access the data with simplexml.